# A Problem with a Proof Concerning the Properties of Orthogonal Matricies

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthonormal

OK, I'm working on the following problem and don't understand how my Linear Algebra text has made it to a certain conclusion here is the problem:

> Let **u** be a unit vector in $R^{n}$ and let $H = I - 2\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T}$.  Show that H is both orthogonal and hence it's own inverse.

So here is the work, I've done and it corresponds with the book, up until a point anyway:

> $H^{T} = (I − 2\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T})^{T} $
>
> $ = I^{T} − 2(\textbf{u}^{T})^{T} \textbf{u}^{T} $
>
> $ = I − 2\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} = H$

So far so good...

> $H^{T}H = H^{2}$
>
> $ = (I − 2\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} )^{2} $
>
> $ = I − 4\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} + 4\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} \textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} $

It's at this point the textbook's answer diverges from mine, and states that the previous statement is equal to $ I - 4\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} + 4\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T}$.  While this is what I want, why is $4\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} \textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T} = 4\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T}$ and not say equal to some value $4(\textbf{u}\textbf{u}^{T})^{2}$?

Comment: Rewrite $4uu^Tuu^T$ as $4u(u^Tu)u^T$. The term in the parenthesis is just $1$. Do you see why? (Hint: Dot product of a unit vector with itself...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is that $\mathbf{u}$ is a *unit* vector. This means that $$\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{u} = \|\mathbf{u}\|^2 = 1$$
You then have 
$$4\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T} = 4\mathbf{u}(\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}\mathbf{u})\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T} = 4\mathbf{u}\|\mathbf{u}\|^2\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}=4\mathbf{u}\mathbf{u}^\mathrm{T}$$

Comment: That piece of knowledge was apparently partially digested, if ever actually consumed.  Thanks!